# adding date to end of the entry

Tags: php

I'm new to these jobs. There is a problem I cannot solve.
If the field is blank while entering the record, date is recording:

```
if(!empty($_POST)) 
    if(empty($_POST['travel'])) 
        $_POST['travel'] = date("d.m.Y") ;
```

Even though something is written in this field, I want to add a date in the same way.
So can a `date("d.m.Y")` be added whether something is written or not?

**solved with this:**

```
if(isset($_POST)) 
    if(isset($_POST['travel'])) 
        $_POST['travel'] .= " - " . date("d.m.Y") ;
```

but now i cannot get date when 'travel' is empty. how can i get date event field is empty or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$_POST['travel'] .= date("d.m.Y") ;
```

Comment: didn't work. I wonder if I can add something like "if it's not empty" ?

Comment: solved with this: if(isset($_POST)) if(isset($_POST['travel'])) $_POST['travel'] .= " - " . date("d.m.Y") ;  // thank you.

Comment: this time, if the field is blank I can't get the date.